# How to right-align plots in a .png?

Tags: r

I have three plots saved to ET1, ET2, and ET3 where each plots different y-axis values but all have the same x-axis values. The y-axis labels are different lengths, so the vertical lines for the x-axis dates do not line up when saving as a .png

```
png(filename="C:/plotting/3_part_data/ET.png", width=650, height=850, units="px", res=100)
grid.arrange(ET1,ET2,ET3,ncol=1,nrow=3)
dev.off()
```

[Current result of the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPyWf.png); you can see where the three vertical lines don't align.

Since there are no elements that change size on the right of any of the plots, I was wondering if there is a way to align them on the right side when saving as .png?

Thanks for pointing towards the other question; this is what worked for me:

```
library(gtable)

# Start png
png(filename="C:/G.png", width=650, height=850, units="px", res=100)

# Get the ggplot grobs
gA <- ggplotGrob(ET1)  
gB <- ggplotGrob(ET2)
gC <- ggplotGrob(ET3)

# Combine the plots
g = cbind.gtable(rbind.gtable(gA, gB, gC, size = "max"), size = "max")

# Draw it
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `cowplot` package and its `align_plots()` function